# Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library'

Tags: android, android-studio

pls help to fix it i can't read hard gramar english

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Fluk\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\animated-vector-drawable\23.4.0\animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar'.
```

Full Build Code.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:mobile:generateDebugSources, :mobile:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :mobile:mockableAndroidJar, :mobile:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
:mobile:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:checkDebugManifest
:mobile:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Fluk\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\animated-vector-drawable\23.4.0\animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar'.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.243 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Thank for help.

Comment: Try to lower the version of com.android.support:appcompat in your gradle then try to run the app again

Comment: sorry sir. notwork :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first post & comment.

I've tried to solve this issue since last week.

Now I found it, you should use JAVA 1.7 and node 4.4.5 LTS

Then you will pass that error, but will stuck at other one error again.

Install JAVA 1.8 then you will succeed.

(I don't know why. Sorry for that)

Hope you can fix :D